# Can someone explain virtual adapters a bit more in depth?

Tags: networking, virtualization, network-adapter

I do know that virtual adapters are used by virtual machines and vpn, but I don't understand how they actually work:

1. Once a virtual adapter is created, is it some kind of pure software independent of a physical nic just running by os? or is it located inside the nic, taking part from physical hardware?
2. If I don't have a physical adapter, can I still create a virtual one to communicate with my virtual machines
3. Simple explanation of how it works or at least some resourses to read about it, obiously I've been searching but there is just really basic descriptions which doesn't help much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A virtual netowrk adapter is just that, a *virtual* adapter.  They dont exist physically, as they are just software.  They can be tied to a physical adapter, but that isnt necessary.
2. This will depend entirely on the virtualization software and its requirements, but there is no reason for it to be mandatory.  I do not know of any that require a physical adapter.
3. I suspect there isnt much to read, as there isnt much to them.  A virtual adapter just emulates a real one.

Comment: Just to add regarding 2. - VMs running on the host without physical adapters will have no connectivity outside the host. Should be obvious, but I learned it is better to mention obvious things too (I work in support ;) )

Comment: Yeah I was aware of that hehe, but still thanks!